# Derivative of trace involving hadamard product and product of inverse matrices

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, hadamard-product

I need to find the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{\Omega}$ of

$$
 Tr\left(\left(\left(\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}\right)\mathbf{S}\right)
$$

In the above, $\mathbf{\Omega}^{-1}$ is symmetric, $\mathbf{C}$  is symmetric, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbf{S}$ is symmetric.

I understand that writing this using $:$ notation might help, which if I'm correct allows me to write

$$
\begin{align}
\phi&=\left(\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}:\mathbf{S}\\
&=\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}:\mathbf{I}\circ\mathbf{S}
\end{align}
$$

However from there I'm unsure - do I need a version of the product rule to deal with the right hand side - in which case how is this written when using $:$ notation? Or using the rule that $d\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}=-\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}d\mathbf{\Omega}\,\,\mathbf{\Omega^{-1}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, that is the correct product rule.

Here is a useful relationship when $A,B$ are symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Sym}(X) &\doteq \tfrac 12\left(X+X^T\right) \\
d(BAB) &= dB\,AB + BA\,dB \\
 &= dB\,AB + (dB\,AB)^T \\
 &= 2\;{\rm Sym}(dB\,AB) \\
}$$

Putting the pieces together yields
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1}\circ I):S \\
 &= (I\circ S):\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1} \\\\
d\phi
 &= (I\circ S):d\left(\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1}\right)
    &\big({\rm sym\,rule}\big) \\
 &= (I\circ S):2\;{\rm Sym}\left(d\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1}\right) \\
 &= 2\;{\rm Sym}(I\circ S):d\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1} \\
 &= 2\;(I\circ S):d\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1} \\
 &= 2\;(I\circ S)\Omega^{-1}C:d\Omega^{-1}
    &\big({\rm product\,rule}\big) \\
 &= -2\;(I\circ S)\Omega^{-1}C:\Omega^{-1}d\Omega\,\Omega^{-1} \\
 &= -2\;\Omega^{-1}(I\circ S)\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1}:d\Omega \\\\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\Omega}
 &= -2\;\Omega^{-1}(I\circ S)\Omega^{-1}C\Omega^{-1}
    &\big({\rm gradient\,matrix}\big) \\\\
}$$
Here is another identity which was used above
$$\eqalign{
X:{\rm Sym}(Y)
 &= X:\tfrac 12(Y+Y^T) \\
 &= \tfrac 12X:Y + \tfrac 12X:Y^T \\
 &= \tfrac 12X:Y + \tfrac 12X^T:Y \\
 &= \tfrac 12(X+X^T):Y \\
 &= {\rm Sym}(X):Y \\
}$$
A similar identity exists for the function
$${\rm Skew}(X) = \tfrac 12\left(X-X^T\right)$$